# Problem with two WP installation on root and subfolder

Tags: permalinks

Let me give you some context.I have a website.com and website.com/blog with each their own wordpress instal

I created the the blog in the first place, and then the "main" wordpress.

The weird thing is that now, when I want to go to website.com, it automatically redirects me to website.com/blog.

And sometimes it is the opposite, the website works, but the /blog is not existing anymore... (404 or just blank page)
And these two cases are shifting from one to another (not sure how)

Any idea why this happens ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: verify the wp-config.php files in the root folder and in /blog folder, they must have different db configuration. Also check the .htacess files

Comment: my ht acces is as such on the main. And the db are different  


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>